# Allow System.exit only for certain classes

Tags: java, securitymanager, system.exit

We are having a Java 1.7 application, that supports plugins, which customers can program in Java. We want to restrict the plugins however from calling System.exit. We can do this via a SecurityManager. However, in the core application there are rare situation when we want to call System.exit. Is there a way to exclude classes or packages from a SecurityManager?

Comment: Sure, granting permissions based on configurable criteria is the primary purpose of a `SecurityManager`. Maybe you want to read [some documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this :

```
private static class ExitTrappedException extends SecurityException 
{ 
} 
private static void forbidSystemExitCall()
{ 
    final SecurityManager securityManager = new SecurityManager() { 
         public void checkPermission( Permission permission ) 
        { 
              if( "exitVM".equals( permission.getName() ) ) 
            {  
                    throw new ExitTrappedException() ; 
            }
        }
    } ; 
    System.setSecurityManager( securityManager ) ; 
} 

private static void enableSystemExitCall() 
{  
       System.setSecurityManager( null ) ; 
}
```

This is inside your class from which plugin is invoked.

put you plugin call between `forbidSystemExitCall` and `enableSystemExitCall`.

Comment: That won't really help, since a malicious plugin may still disable or replace the security manager before calling System.exit().

Comment: @jarnbjo We would further modify our custom SecurityManager to check for the "setSecurityManager" Permission, which is checked according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setSecurityManager%28java.lang.SecurityManager%29

Comment: @Benjamin: Sure you can make the security manager deny that it is replaced with a new manager or disabled, but still this approach wouldn't work. Peter's suggestion (use the stack trace to check where the method is ivoked from) is probably much better.

Comment: @jarnbjo I agree with the stacktrace check. Do you see any other reasons that checking the "setSecurityManager" Permission won't work, besides having probably difficulties of setting it to null from our code?

Comment: You won't probably have problems setting it to null from your code, it simply won't be possible. If you allow the security manager to be disabled or otherwise modified without checking who is doing the modification, you can not make sure that the modification is not coming from a malicious plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Batty's answer except you can disable setting the security manager again and override the checkExit() method.  What I would do is allow calls to System.exit() but this should trigger the plugin to stop/unload rather than exit the whole JVM.

You can use a Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() to work out which code called the System.exit();

Comment: There is also the `protected Class<?>[] SecurityManager.getClassContext()`, which might be easier to use.